# resolve timer logic

Tags: java, android

i did fastforward in music player by getting current time of the player (30 sec forward)

```
if(sec>=maxsec && min>=maxmin && hour>=maxhour)
      {
        next_buttonclick(null);

      }
    else 
    {
        sec=sec+30;
         if(sec>=60)
         {
          sec=sec%60;
          min=min+1;
             if(min>=60)
             {
                 min=min%60;
                 hour=hour+1;                
             }

         }
```

max is the time duration of media..

when i run this, it not working properly..
plz fix bug free..

also reverse

```
if(sec<=0 && min<=0 && hour<=0)
    {
        back_buttonclick(null);

    }
    else 
    {
        gettimeduration();
        sec=sec-30;
         if(sec<0)
         {
             sec=60+sec;
             min=min-1;
             if(min<0)
             {
                 min=60+sec;
                 hour=hour-1;

             }

         }
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: WOW! writing multi-language source files is hard enough for just C and C++, but you are attempting 3 languages ... good luck and have fun!

Comment: I suspect that you're using `&&` when you mean `||`, but if you want us to help you, give us better information, e.g. what the code is doing wrong. And work on your formats, spelling, punctuation and grammar.

Comment: plz try to fix ur code urself 1st!

Comment: both forward and reverse ,not does exact seeking operation i mean 30 seconds..

Comment: time format is 01:03:30 like that i separated by scanner and got hr,min,sec

Comment: Nope sorry, SO is not a submit-your-code-and-let-others-debug-for-you resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the condition

```
(sec>=maxsec && min>=maxmin && hour>=maxhour)
```

doesn't do what you think it should.
Imagine that `maxsec` is 30; `maxmin` is 6, and `maxhour` is 0. And let's say `sec` is 17, `min` is 8, and `hour` is 0. So the maxtime is 6 and a half minutes and the current time is 8 minutes and 17 seconds.

```
17 >= 30 FALSE and the whole condition becomes false
```

The best thing to do when comparing times is to convert to seconds and compare just the seconds

```
(sec + min*60 + hour*3600 >= maxsec + maxmin*60 + maxhour*3600)
```

Comment: The answer would demonstrate the problem better if the current time were say, 2 minutes. As it stands, then your example current time is over the sample max time.

Comment: @DeadMG: right, 8 minutes and 17 seconds is larger than 6 minutes and 30 seconds, but the condition says it isn't :)